# How to download all Noto fonts

Tags: fonts

Linguist here. On my old Windows computer, I downloaded all the Google Noto fonts. It was easy because they came all together in a package (a ZIP file, probably). Now I want to do the same on my computer (also Windows), but the new Google Fonts website https://fonts.google.com/noto seems to only allow downloading one font family at a time. How can I get them all?

Comment: Maybe a good question for Google, certainly not to random people on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

The place you want to go is [the noto-fonts repository on Github](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/). The [latest zipped-up release](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/releases/tag/v20201206-phase3) is from December 6, 2020. (This is also where they take the bug reports)

Updates to individual fonts, and occasionally new fonts for scripts not previously covered, occur every few weeks. Probably the best way to keep up with them is to install the [GitHub Desktop application](https://desktop.github.com/) and add the noto-fonts repository ([help page](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/installing-and-configuring-github-desktop)). This creates a copy of noto-fonts on your computer that you can keep up to date.

Comment: For anyone taking a look at this after 2020, use this link: 
https://github.com/notofonts/notofonts.github.io

That's where noto fonts are released nowadays, once a month there's a new release with all fonts packed into a zip file. The old repo has been archived.